# sharing enabled by default in 22.04

Tags: sharing, 22.04

I installed Ubuntu 22.04 today and I noticed sharing was enabled by default. is this normal behavior? how can I prevent it on new installs?

Answer (score 0):

It can be disabled permanently by `uninstall gnome-remote-desktop`,

```
sudo apt remove gnome-remote-desktop
sudo apt autoclean && sudo apt autoremove
```

I finally get rid of it.

Comment: Do remember to reboot your device.